# Webpack 2 multiple targets in config file, how to specify target with CLI

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My webpack config exports an array of config objects. One has a target of `web` and the other `node`. I don't want to split this into separate files.

When I use the CLI to build I get both targets building. However, I want to specify which target. In the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#advanced-options) there is a target flag available but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried this as per the docs:

`webpack --config webpack.config.js --target='node'`

But I still get both the node and web targets building.

Answer (score -1):

1) I saw in the documentation, the *--target* is use without quotes, please try to review it.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html

2) Have you try use 2 different webpack.config.js files, one for **web** and another one for **node**, applying some specific logic?. I did it once in order to identify differents environments and it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I looked at point 1, that's for webpack 1 and doesn't work for 2. Also I'd like to keep my config in one file. I've just updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Also "have you tried..." questions should be put into the comments rather than as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's because I don't have yet permissions to write comments :(

Answer (score -1):

use `--config-name 'your target name'`